# How is Zoom able to launch itself from the browser?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, web, v8

When opening a Zoom link, the browsers shows a popup that asks if you'd like to launch zoom. Then, the Zoom desktop installation is launched.

What is the mechanism for doing this? I thought you couldn't access the local system from Javascript.

[image]